# Inserting into a database with ASP.NET causes error

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, vb.net

I am working with VS 2017 for the first time.

I am trying to insert some values into a database. I already made the connection (checked with select statement) with the database, but now I am stuck in the insert portion.

I have a `SqlDataSource` defined as:

```
<div>
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="  <%$ ConnectionStrings:Sphinxx_Conn %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Sphinxx_Conn.ProviderName %>"  
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO &quot;DEMO&quot; (&quot;ID&quot;, &quot;NAME&quot;) VALUES (:ID, :NAME)">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="NAME" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
   </asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
```

Now the following snippet:

```
 SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["ID"].DefaultValue = '1'
 SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["NAME"].DefaultValue = 'John'
```

Underlines the 'SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters' part and shows an error:

> Property access must assign to the property or use its value.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing invalid data because you are using single quotes, use double quotes instead:

```
 SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["ID"].DefaultValue = "1";
 SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["NAME"].DefaultValue = "John";
```

On the side note, if you started working and getting to know web development with Visual Studio, i recommend you to look at MVC. Web Forms are old tech that is no longer supported.

Comment: SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["ID"].DefaultValue = "1";
       SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["NAME"].DefaultValue = "John";

Changing the code with double quotes doesn't solve it. Still getting that
'Property access must assign to the property or use its value.' error.

Comment: Do you use this code in proper method scope? Can you show whole code file in which error is?

Comment: You need to add your code in code behind file, not in aspx file. Place it in Default.aspx.vb file.

Comment: `<%@ Page aspcompat=true Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="TestDemo._Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<%
         SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["ID"].DefaultValue = "2"
         SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["NAME"].DefaultValue = "John"
 %>
</asp:Content>`
This is all there is. The <div> tag which I gave in the question goes just before the <% tag for the SqlDataSource. The comment space here isn't letting me paste the entire thing.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What exactly to write in the .aspx.vb file?
As of now the contents there are
`Public Class _Default
    Inherits Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

End Class` 
 Thanks for your response.

Comment: add these lines in Page_Load method.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 errors within your Code Snippet of assigning values.

1. You are setting a `char` value instead of `string`, replace single quoted `'`values with double quotes ". Instead of `'1'` do this `"1"` same with John too.
2. You have not used `;` to terminate your statement, so put semicolons in the end of your statements.

Comment: SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["ID"].DefaultValue = "1"; SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["NAME"].DefaultValue = "John";

 Changing the code with double quotes doesn't solve it. Still getting that 'Property access must assign to the property or use its value.' error.